# Escape HTML in bash ( Ubuntu server )

Tags: bash, html, javascript

I have already html file ( Form ) that contains HTML Tags , css , Javascript and some of XOR cipher

I used a website to escape HTML then I write in bash file:

```
header= ' The HTML code after the escaping '
echo $header > test.html
```

But I got an empty test.html file!
How can I print html in bash?

Comment: 1. shell variable assignment _must not_ have spaces around `=`; 2. you should quote the variable: `echo "$header"`

Comment: You are right about number 1. but I still get an empty file ..

Comment: Define your variable with double quotes like so `header="........"` for charachter escaping to work correctly and escape characters that need to be escaped with a backslash. Add the variable definition you used if you need more help.

Comment: You still have a space after the `=`. The header variable is empty.